# Open link in new tab using attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

For example see the code below.Clicking on link must open `http://google.com` in new tab.Like in site [demo link](http://couponcoupon.biz/coupon-codes/coupon-codes-for-dominos-pizza-january-2013/)

```
<p class="coupon"><a name="http://google.com">link</a></p>
```

I dont know how demo link has achived it.Can Any one help me how to do it ?Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following javascript (using jQuery) :

```
$('.coupon a').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

This way the link will open in a new tab or a new window (depending on the user preferences).

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
<p class="coupon"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">link</a></p>
```

Javascript alternative

```
$(function(){
  $(".coupon a").click(function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('name'), '_blank');
  });
});
```

Comment: I dont want to be href, I am doing this for seo.So there is no external links.Can you please say how demo link is doing it ?

Comment: That maKes no sense RE SEO. Without the `href`, you are forcing people to use a mouse, if you don't/can't use a mouse, you won't be able to use the site.

Comment: Added Javascript option, requires JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**Your demo link is achieving this in following manner :**

**You need to get the following scripts**

**1.** http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js

**2.** http://doc.qt.digia.com/qdoc/config-scripts-superfish-js.html

**3.** http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/plugins/cookie/jquery.cookie.js?r=6125

**4.** jquery.jcarousel.js from http://sorgalla.com/projects/download-zip.php?jcarousel

**Then make your own js file and add this in it**

```
function padd_append_clear() {
    jQuery('.append-clear').append('<div class="clear"></div>');
}

function padd_toggle(classname,value) {
jQuery(classname).focus(function() {
    if (value == jQuery(classname).val()) {
        jQuery(this).val('');
    }
});
jQuery(classname).blur(function() {
    if ('' == jQuery(classname).val()) {
        jQuery(this).val(value);
    }
});
}

function padd_slideshow_init(carousel) {
carousel.clip.hover(function() {
    carousel.stopAuto();
}, function() {
    carousel.startAuto();
});
}

function padd_create_slideshow() {
jQuery('#slideshow > .list').jcarousel({
    auto: 5,
    animation: 1000,
    wrap: 'circular',
    initCallback: padd_slideshow_init
});
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery('div#menubar div > ul').superfish({
    autoArrows: false,
    hoverClass: 'hover',
    speed: 500,
    animation: { opacity: 'show', height: 'show' }
});
jQuery('div#menubar div > ul > li:last-child').css({
    'background': 'transparent none',
    'padding-right' : '0'
});

padd_append_clear();
padd_create_slideshow();

jQuery('p.coupon a').click(function() {
    window.open(jQuery(this).attr('name'));
});

jQuery('input#s').val('Find a coupon');
padd_toggle('input#s','Find a coupon');

jQuery('div.search form').click(function () {
    jQuery('input#s').focus();
});

});
```

**Once done now you can import these js files in your html page and achieve your desired functionality by name tag also.**